# Seeking list of Jewish Cemeteries in the USA

Tags: united-states, jewish, cemeteries

I am seeking a searchable list of the Jewish cemeteries in the USA, especially the larger, still active cemeteries.  By searchable, I mean that it is possible to search by cemetery name and also sort by cemetery name.

Ideally, the list would contain:
cemetery name
street address
city
state
URL

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8):

Your best bet is to check the International Association of Jewish Genealogy Societies:  [IAJGS International Jewish Cemetery Project](http://www.iajgsjewishcemeteryproject.org/).

[On their United States Page](http://www.iajgsjewishcemeteryproject.org/united-states/index.html), they have almost 1400 Jewish burial sites cataloged from every state. One burial site (e.g. a town or district) may contain several Jewish cemeteries.

They try to give location and contact information for each cemetery, including address, phone and/or email, and website if they have one. There may be a lot more information as well, including history of the cemetery, the number of burials, and some even have a burial list or point you to other information.

They also have a wonderful [Please Read First](http://www.iajgsjewishcemeteryproject.org/instructions-information/index.html) section, which includes among other information: [What Makes a Cemetery Jewish?](http://www.iajgsjewishcemeteryproject.org/what-makes-a-cemetery-jewish/index.html)

Comment: This url claims to list 2,366 Jewish cemeteries.  But this list, like the one you link to, is cumbersome to use.  It is not possible to search the list by name of a cemetery.

Comment: @GrandpaJoe - You are talking about the Jewish Online Worldwide Burial Registry (JOWBR) at: http://www.jewishgen.org/databases/Cemetery/tree/CemList.htm - which lists burials, not cemeteries. The IAJGS project in my answer is for cemeteries. At the top right of each page of the IAJGS project is a search box, and you can search the list by the name of a cemetery. The IAJGS project is a more complete list because the JOWBR does not list  cemeteries that it has no burials for.

Comment: @lk  The search on that page is worldwide, so produces many false drops. Also, the numbers on the page add up to 1,008 and the jewishgen page claims 2,366.  Do you know if there is complete overlap or is the total large than in either list?

Comment: @GrandpaJoe - I'm not saying it's perfect, but it is the best there is. The IAJGS project is a more complete list because the JOWBR does not list cemeteries that it has no burials for. The JOWBR count is not cemeteries, but burial sites (e.g. a town or district) that may contain several Jewish cemeteries. So there are many more cemeteries in the JOWBR lists than what the sites totals add up to.

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility is to look at the list of members of the Jewish Cemetery Association of North America:

https://www.jcana.org/members/all-members

Some of the members are cemeteries, and some are regional associations, such as the Jewish Cemetery Association of Massachusetts, which has address information on over 200 Jewish cemeteries in the state, even if they are not members of the association:

https://www.jcam.org/Pages/Cemeteries/Cemetery_Pages/Alpha_by_Name.htm

Note in this case they list 222 cemeteries, while JOWBR lists 158 cemeteries, and the IAJGS site lists 62 burial locations for the state. Some of the discrepancy may have to do with how cemeteries are defined, and if a cemetery with 10 sections owned by different organizations is considered one cemetery or 10, but either way this kind of checking should provide more information.

Answer (score 2):

[OpenStreetMap data](https://www.openstreetmap.org) (OSM) is interesting source of data - contains also cemeteries from all over the world - including position and description. Unfortunately it is quite hard to extract from the OSM database. Luckily I have found a service that can [extract cemeteries from OSM database](https://mygeodata.cloud/data/download/osm/cemeteries/united-states-of-america--connecticut) for US countries, regions and cities and export to various formats - KML, CSV, XLSX...